# HP Pavilion G6 numpad not working in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, hp, numpad, xev

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 on a HP Pavilion G6 and having a little bit of difficulty getting Ubuntu to recognise the numpad. So far I have tried running `numlockx on` with no luck and also looked at changing the keyboard layout but i just can't seem to get it to work. What seems to be happening is the numlock works but the numbers on the numpad and the surrounding characters do not. I even tried checking `xev` but even that didn't pick anything on the numpad other than the numlock. Please could someone help as i am running out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "mousekeys" option?

That, toggles  which use the NumPad to control the mouse pointer.

Short way: **Shift + NumLock**

Using settings:

- Step 1: Click on System Menu
- Step 2: Mouse over on Preferences
- Step 3: Click on Keyboard (This brings up the Keyboard preferences window.)
- Step 4: Click on the Mouse Keys tab
- Step 5: Disable the “Allow to control the pointer using the keyboard” checkbox.
- Step 6: Click close and ensure that your Num lock is on.

[Source](http://www.rvdavid.net/how-to-get-the-use-of-your-number-pad-back-in-ubuntu/).